# why does the print function command twice?

Tags: python, string, function

The below python code is my project on caesar cipher

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
def caesar(plain_text,shift_num,direction):
  if direction == "encode":
    encoded_text = ''
    for letter in plain_text:
      encoded_text = ''
      encoded_text += alphabet[alphabet.index(letter)+shift_num]
    print(f"the encoded text is {encoded_text}")
  elif direction == "decode":
    decoded_text = ''
    for letter in plain_text:
      decoded_text += alphabet[alphabet.index(letter)-shift_num]
    print(f"the decoded text is {decoded_text}")
caesar(plain_text = text,shift_num = shift,direction=direction)
```

The above code performs a console where the print function is performed twice. for both encode and decode the print function has two answers. Why do i encounter this problem in my code?

Comment: I'm not getting any double printing from the code you've provided. However, note that in your first `for` loop, you are overwriting the value of `encoded_text` on every iteration, resetting it back to an empty string.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Please make a [mre]. You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and check out [ask] for more tips.

Comment: It would be MUCH easier to help you, if you gave several specific examples of input and output. For example, if your input was only one or two letters, then the next question would be "what happens if you give a longer input"? If the result was even MORE printing, that would be a huge clue as to what is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go:-
The improved version. I imported string so you don't have to make an alphabet list.

```
import string
direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
def caesar(plain_text,shift_num,direction):
    e_msg = ""
    if direction == "encode":
        for i in plain_text:
            if not i == " ":
                e_msg += string.ascii_lowercase[(string.ascii_lowercase.index(i) + shift) % 26]
            else:
                e_msg += " "
        print(e_msg)
    elif direction == "decode":
        for i in plain_text:
            if not i == " ":
                e_msg += string.ascii_lowercase[(string.ascii_lowercase.index(i) - shift) % 26]
            else:
                e_msg += " "
        print(e_msg)

caesar(plain_text = text,shift_num = shift,direction=direction)
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. Just shows an alternative way to code. Also adds details not shown in the original (handling space character). Wasn't asked for, so seems off-purpose to me. BTW, look up definition of "improvised".

Comment: Thanks for telling me the "improvised" error in my English. In my defense, I am a 14-year-old kid from a country that doesn't even have English as the primary language.

Comment: I figured it wasn't your native language :)  Congrats on having your answer accepted by the question-asker!